# jspdf creates empty pdf's

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I am using JsPDF and want to create pdf from content inside a Section tag.
i have tryed alot of guides but noone seam to work, and due to lack of demo code, i see no other alternative than try my luck here.

After implemented code, i manage to generate pdf but its all white, and i would like to get the "save" options after generate to.

**My code:**

```
<section id="content" class="printable">
 my data
</section>

<a href="javascript:demoFromHTML()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"> Pdf</a>
```

```
<script>
     function demoFromHTML() {
         var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'in', 'letter');
         var source = $('.printable').first();
         var specialElementHandlers = {
             '#bypassme': function(element, renderer) {
                 return true;
             }
         };

         doc.fromHTML(
            $('.printable').get(0), // [Refer Exact code tutorial][2]HTML string or DOM elem ref.
             0.5,    // x coord
             0.5,    // y coord
             {
                 'width': 7.5, // max width of content on PDF
                 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
             });

         doc.output('dataurl');
    }
</script>
```

**included script:**

```
<script src="//mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any recent update on this issue for reactjs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"> 
</script> 

<script>
var lMargin = 15; //left margin in mm
var rMargin = 15; //right margin in mm
var pdfInMM = 210; // width of A4 in mm

function getPDF() {
  var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
  var tavern = document.querySelector(".printable").innerText;
  var lines = doc.splitTextToSize(tavern, pdfInMM - lMargin - rMargin);
  doc.text(lMargin, 20, lines);
  doc.save("Generated.pdf");
}
</script>
```

And your markup:

```
<a href="javascript:getPDF()" class="button">Run Code</a>

<section id="content" class="printable">
my data
</section>
```